# When "be it" is at the beginning of a sentence, what kind of structure do you call it?

Tags: american-english, british-english, subject-verb-inversion

I think it is kind of inversion and I'd found some info on Wikipedia, but I cannot recall what term this structure is, I even remember some examples from Wiki, say, "be it ever so humble, there's no place like home."
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Fi Fi Fo Fum, I smell the blood of an Englishman.   Be he live or be he dead, I'll grind his bones to butter my bread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of morphology, the verb is in the subjunctive mood (*be* rather than indicative *is*).
In terms of word order, we’re dealing with a case of subject-auxiliary inversion (*be* before the subject).
In terms of semantics, the structure can express a variety of meanings such as optative, a wish or a hope (*be it the best year of your life*), in which case the structure carries archaic, formal, often religious connotations. But in your case it encodes arbitrariness or free-choice, ‘no matter which’ (*be it new or be it old*), or concession, ‘although, even if, even if I grant’ (*be it as it may*). The two uses are difficult to distinguish.

So your construction could be described quite well as a case of **subject-auxiliary inversion with free-choice/concessive, subjunctive *be*.**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaining Richard I learnt a lot; btw I just succeeded in locating it on the Inversion section of the English subjunctive on wikipedia and that's exactly what I wanted to find.

Comment: @Angyang Please mark this answer as your accepted answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @Angyang On the other hand, if you mean that either [English subjunctive § Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Inversion) or [English conditional sentences § Inversion in condition clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Inversion_in_condition_clauses) answered your question, can you please post an answer with those details?